# Update custom attributes to product using rest

Tags: magento2, php, product-attribute, rest-api

```
$data = [
    "product" => [
        "sku"=> $productsku,
        // "attribute_set_id"=> 4,
        //"attribute_set_id" => $mage_attr_set_id,
        // "entity_type_id" => $entity_type_id,
        "visibility" => 2,
        // "custom_attributes" => $subArray
        "custom_attributes" => [
            [
                "attribute_code" => "selling_unit_of_measure",
                "value" => "each"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

To update product using Postman and REST API

URL: /rest/V1/products/{SKU}
Method : PUT

the JSON data to pass or you can take reference on product JSON string from
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/create-simple-products/

or https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-update-product-using-rest-api-in-magento-2/

```
{
  "product": {
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "value": "54"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```